# How to vertically and horizontally center SVG text with different font size

Tags: svg, react-native

I have a component to represent a tab header like the following :

```
import Svg, { G, Path } from 'react-native-svg';

const Tab = ({ height = "57.8", width="104", children, fill='#D1D3D4' }) => (
  <Svg height={height} width={width} viewBox="0 0 104 57.8">
    <G>
      <Path d="M-0.1,57.8h85c19.1,0,19.5-13.9,19.1-17.9L97.8,0H0.1L-0.1,57.8z" fill={fill}/>
      { children }
    </G>
  </Svg>
)
```

The children is to be svg Text that will have multiple text segments with different font size to be baseline aligned between each other. This text also need to be vertically AND horizontally centered inside it's parent.

I have tried different things, but I can't seem to find the proper configuration. This is my latest which centers the inside text baseline with the center of it's parent.

```
import { Text, TSpan } from 'react-native-svg';
...
return (<Tab><Text x={52} y={28.9} textAnchor={'middle'} alignmentBaseline={'central'}>
  <TSpan alignmentBaseline={"baseline"}>
    <TSpan fontSize={44}>{text.charAt(0)}</TSpan>
    <TSpan fontSize={32}>{text.substring(1)}</TSpan>
  </TSpan>
</Text></Tab>)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG has no automatic layout capabilities. You are required to position text yourself using the `x` and `y` attributes and/or the `transform` attribute.

However, you can embed HTML in an SVG using the `<foreignObject>` element.  If you do that you can use HTMLs layout capabilities to center text horizontally and vertically.

You can find examples of how to use `<foreignObject>` on this site.

**Update**

I think part of the reason why you are having so much trouble, is that `alignment-baseline` is not inherited.  Also the browsers don't seem to agree on how to render it. IT generally works on `<text>` elements, but things get a lot messier/buggier when you put it on `<tspan>` elements.

I would suggest using the `dy="Xem"` technique instead.  It works the same on every browser.

```html
<svg width="104" height="57.8" viewBox="0 0 104 57.8">
  <line x1="0" y1="28.9" x2="104" y2="28.9" stroke="red" stroke-width="1"/>
  <text x="52" y="28.9" dy="0.35em" font-size="44" text-anchor="middle">
    <tspan>T</tspan><tspan font-size="32">ext</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I already have specified the X and Y position of the text to be added inside the SVG. I also specified text-anchor and alignment-baseline which works fine with a single text element having a single font to center it but where the problems lies is when I try to apply this to text that has different fonts size that has to be baseline aligned within each segment on the same line. As far as I know, SVG knows how to compute font width and all, but I just can't seem to make the "centering" applied to the proper element. I have limited knowledge of SVG so maybe I use tspan in a wrong way.

Comment: Unless my understanding of the text-anchor and alignment-baseline is wrong and can't be applied to a "text group" ?

Comment: Can you clarify the rationale behind the magic number "0.35em" so I can generalize this to other font sizes ? What formula did you use to come up with that number ? My SVG data is dynamically generated and other text with different font size will need to be rendered as well.

Comment: It will vary with the font.  It'll depend on factors like: how the font is positioned within the em box, the x-height, etc. But once you find a suitable value for the font you are using, it will work for any font size you set. I didn't do it here, but it's a good idea to specify a particular font, so you know the browser is using the font for which you selected the em value. The em value I used here might not be right for the default font another browser uses.